# goinstant.connect not working on deployed mobile app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, icenium, goinstant, goinstant-platform

The app is developed using Icenium and Apache Cordova.

GoInstant connects just fine in the simulator on my computer. However, as soon as I create a build provision and deploy it, connecting fails after 10s or so with the error that it reached the maximum attempts.

I have confirmed it is on the line goinstant.connect. I have also confirmed that the token and room are the same in the simulator as they are the build provision.

I figured it could be domain issues, but I wasn't sure there would be a difference since the simulator is supposed to, well, simulate. I have confirmed the app has permissions to access internet (contact to my api through jquery ajax is working), and that the phone is connected to the internet. Issue happens on both wifi and data.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Matt, we're looking into this issue. Could you please send us your GoInstant account and App name to support@goinstant.com

Comment: After walking through the issue with the guys at GoInstant the issue was resolved by uninstalling and reinstalling my .apk... boo! Not sure what the cause of the issue was but I will post back if I find anything.